# variable not available despite public method

Tags: java, android, scope, public

The `float targetVolume` in created in a `public void` method, but cannot be resolved in another `public void` method...

```
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            float x = (float) Math.random();
            if (x < 0.5){
                float targetVolume = 0;
            } else {
                float targetVolume = 1;
            }

            scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (targetVolume.equals (1)){
                        mp.setVolume(startingVolume+volumeIncrement, startingVolume+volumeIncrement);
                    } else {
                        mp.setVolume(startingVolume-volumeIncrement, startingVolume-volumeIncrement);
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I can solve the problem by adding the final modifier to the float:

```
        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            float x = (float) Math.random();
            final float targetVolume=(x < 0.5)?0:1;

            scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (targetVolume >startingVolume){
                        startingVolume = startingVolume+volumeIncrement;
                        mp.setVolume((startingVolume), (startingVolume));
                        }
                    else if (targetVolume < startingVolume){
                        startingVolume = startingVolume-volumeIncrement;
                        mp.setVolume((startingVolume), (startingVolume));
                        }              
                }
            }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However, does the final float targetVolume now hold the same value (a zero or a 1) each time the task is run? I need this value to change randomly...

Comment: Read up on variable scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088299/what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-instance-variables-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared it locally to that method

```
cheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        float x = (float) Math.random();
        if (x <0.5){
            float targetVolume =0;}
```

declare it as a member variable to the class to have class scope. This means to define it anywhere outside of a method (usually just before `onCreate()` for an `Activity`).

[Read about Java variable scope](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2FjavaOO%2Fvariables.html&ei=E9brUpX-O8ekyQH0z4GQCw&usg=AFQjCNGE9PAuuz3XTocu73B5NKp8or-8WA&sig2=iIrwwHhs3J41HWiEw9a2ug&bvm=bv.60444564,d.aWc)

Comment: This DID make the float available, HOWEVER does the final float targetVolume now hold the same value (a zero or a 1) each time the task is run? I need this value to change randomly...

Comment: It doesn't need to be `final` since it is a member variable. Don't make it `static` and you should be fine

Comment: The variable needs to be created inside that method in order for it to change at set time intervals though...

Comment: No, it just needs to be initialized there (given a value). Declare it as a member variable (`float targetVolume;`)

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        float x = (float) Math.random();
        final float targetVolume=(x < 0.5)?0:1;

        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (targetVolume==1){
                    mp.setVolume(startingVolume+volumeIncrement, startingVolume+volumeIncrement);
                } else {
                    mp.setVolume(startingVolume-volumeIncrement, startingVolume-volumeIncrement);
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: This DID make the float available, HOWEVER does the final float targetVolume now hold the same value (a zero or a 1) each time the task is run? I need this value to change randomly...