# difference between declaring an object on class level and in methods

Tags: java, class, variables

`A` is another class outside of test

**case 1:**

```
public class Test{



      A testObj;

      public static void main(String[] args){
         testObj=new A();
         testObj.methodInsideClassA();
      }
}
```

**case 2:**

```
 public class Test{


      public static void main(String[]  args){
         A testObj = new A();
         testObj.methodInsideClassA();
      }
}
```

so whats the difference between them? And what should I use?

Comment: `Case 1` testObj needs to be declared `static` to compile (hence, is a [static variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html))

Comment: Not sure if it is `Déjà vu` or whether I have come across this question way too many times on this site that I am too lazy to even mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @copeg I ve compiled a case 1 like program without declaring testObj static

Comment: @devilakos If you were able to compile it, then it wasn't "case 1" like. You should mind, that `main` is a `static` method. I guess your program (or the method which you mean was "case 1 like") wasn't static.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between local and instance variables in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088299/what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-instance-variables-in-java)

Comment: @Tom Sorry,my bad i used non-static A  from a non static method called from main(with the use of a Test object)

Comment: @devilakos Yes, that would work. Each non-static method can access every instance field of the class. A static method needs a reference to an instance of the "own" class to do that.

Answer (score 1):

### Case 1

testObj is a class-level variable.

### Case 2

testObj is a local variable.
A local variable is the one that is declared within a method or a constructor.

One important distinction between class-level variable and local variable is that **access specifiers can be applied to class-level variables only** and not to  local variables.

Answer (score 0):

If this object should be shared between some method runs, you should use the first options. In other cases (temporary object), you should use the second.

Comment: Since when did instance variables stop relying on `this`?

Comment: @ChetanKinger where did I say so?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between of the two declaration in the scope of the instance/object of `A`.

In first case the `testObj` is accessible from the all method of class `Test`
In second case the `testObj` is accessible only from the `main()` method of class `Test`. While `main()` method terminated `testObj` also removed from the memory.

What you have to use it depends on situation. Suppose in some case you require the instance of `A`  (that is `testObj` ) in all over of your `Test` class - means several methods of class `Test` uses the same instance of `A`. Then you declare `testObj` outside of all methods of class `Test` - that is as an instance variable.

When different method of class `Test` requires different instance of `A` then you may use method local variable as in case 2.

Comment: Since when did instance variables stop relying on `this`?

Comment: so this works like the normal variable(int,float,char etc) declaration thanks..  and another question...if i use the first case (create an object on class level)  will i have to asign a value to it everytime i want to use it on another method of my class or its value will stay in memory after initialization?