# When to use field variable?

Tags: java, variables

Under what circumstance would you use field variable instead of local variable? I found it a bit hard to decide when a variable is used in 2 or more methods in a class. I tend to use local variables and pass them to another method.

Thanks,

Sarah

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794141/java-instance-variables-vs-local-variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In object-oriented terms, does the variable make sense as an attribute of the object?  If so, you should make it a field variable.  If not, it can go either way.

Remember the Single Responsibility Principle -- well-designed classes should have only 1 responsibility, and thus only 1 reason to change.

Answer (score 7):

A field denotes some kind of state related to an instance of your class.  For instance, a `BankAccount` could have a `balance` field.

You should never use a field to simplify passing data from one method to another method.  That's simply not its purpose.  Doing so also makes your methods intrinsically thread unsafe or require synchronization.

A local variable is just a temporary store of data used to support an operation being done by a method.  For example,

```
public void addInterest(double rate) {
    double toAdd = rate * balance;
    logTransaction("Interest", toAdd);
    balance += toAdd;
}
```

toAdd here makes no sense as a field since it is temporary to the operation, not a part of the account's state.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not pass variables around to other methods unless there's a very specific reason. If the variable is used multiple times in the class, make it a field variable. This almost always makes your code much more flexible too.

In general, you can also think if the variable makes sense as a part of the class. That is, it makes sense to have a `Car` class have the variable `numOfMiles`, even if it's only used a few times. However, if one method is `int GetAmountOfGasUsed(int milesThisTrip)` it makes sense to pass in the miles variable as a local variable because the distance you travel is probably not specific to the car.

Answer (score 0):

If the methods that use the variable need to modify the value as well, then by all means make it a field variable. But, if they only read the value, you can safely pass it around.