# Fields vs Local variables? When to use one or the other?

Tags: oop, refactoring

I have a few questions regarding the use of class fields and local variables.

- **When should a variable be declared as a field or a local variable?** Of course, it's pretty obvious that if a variable only lives in the scope of a block or a function, a variable should only be local.
- What if, after refactoring a function, **the large function gets split up into
  several private functions-- Would this be enough of a reason to
  promote a local variable into a field? How about readability?**
- Would it be better to pass around the local variables among the private functions?
- Instead of promoting into a field, would it be viable to extract a class among functions that use the same local variables?

Anything you could expound on related topics to this would be nice as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Declare a variable as a field when it represents the *state* of the instance.
2. A large function that's been split up isn't enough reason to promote local variables into fields. The impact on readability and maintainability is too significant:

   1. programmers will **always have to reason** whether the fields are part of the state or are they just some temporary calculation helpers;
   2. much, *much* [**harder to maintain thread-safety**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527183/978502) since the same fields are used for any concurrent method invocations.
   3. passing the variables from one inner method to another helps:

      1. independently understanding the exact functionality of the method;
      2. re-use the inner methods;
      3. unit-test the inner methods.
3. Yes, pass around the local variables.
4. In case there are just too much such variables, it's typical to group them in a convenient helper class, that functions as a struct. It increases readability and eases the usage.