# How to add JTable into JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable, jtabbedpane

I am writing a GUI which shows 800 students' table where informations for students are read from a txt file. I wrote a Screen() class and StudentTable() class where Screen class has TabbedPane with two JPanel tabs "PList" and "PChart". I want to add my StudentTable class into my PList JPanel. So when I run Screen class, it will show StudentTable class which has students table inside. Normally, I managed to show my table without tabs.
First, I opened "Students.txt" file, then I read the file. Then I closed the file. After that I created a void method createTable() which creates table. The table gets information from the ArrayList. Now, I want to add this class to my PList JPanel. The code is kinda long. So I uploaded them. However, if you want me to share the code, I can do it aswell.
**Screen.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Screen extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JPanel PList, PChart;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menuStudent, menuSort, menuFilter;
    private JMenuItem addStudent, removeStudent, removeAllStudents;
    private JMenuItem sortLastName, sortId, sortAverage;
    private JMenuItem filterLetterGrade, removeFilter;

    private StudentTable studentTable;

    public Screen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuStudent = new JMenu();
        menuSort = new JMenu();
        menuFilter = new JMenu();
        addStudent = new JMenuItem();
        removeStudent = new JMenuItem();
        removeAllStudents = new JMenuItem();
        sortLastName = new JMenuItem();
        sortId = new JMenuItem();
        sortAverage = new JMenuItem();
        filterLetterGrade = new JMenuItem();
        removeFilter = new JMenuItem();     
        PList = new JPanel();
        PChart = new JPanel();

        studentTable = new StudentTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Screen");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // Menu
        menuStudent.setText("Student");
        addStudent.setText("Add Student");
        addStudent.addActionListener(this);
        removeStudent.setText("Remove Student");
        removeStudent.addActionListener(this);
        removeAllStudents.setText("Remove All Students");
        removeAllStudents.addActionListener(this);
        menuStudent.add(addStudent);
        menuStudent.add(removeStudent);
        menuStudent.add(removeAllStudents);

        menuSort.setText("Sort");
        sortLastName.setText("Sort by last name");
        sortLastName.addActionListener(this);
        sortId.setText("Sort by ID");
        sortId.addActionListener(this);
        sortAverage.setText("Sort by average");
        sortAverage.addActionListener(this);
        menuSort.add(sortLastName);
        menuSort.add(sortId);
        menuSort.add(sortAverage);

        menuFilter.setText("Filter");
        filterLetterGrade.setText("Filter by letter grade");
        filterLetterGrade.addActionListener(this);
        removeFilter.setText("Remove filter");
        removeFilter.addActionListener(this);
        menuFilter.add(filterLetterGrade);
        menuFilter.add(removeFilter);

        menuBar.add(menuStudent);
        menuBar.add(menuSort);
        menuBar.add(menuFilter);

        // Tabs
        tabbedPane.add("List", PList);
        tabbedPane.add("Chart", PChart);
        add(tabbedPane);
        PList.add(studentTable);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Screen();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**StudentTable.java**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class StudentTable extends JPanel {

    private static JTable table;
    private String name, lastName, letterGrade;
    private long studentId;
    private double quiz1,quiz2,project,midterm,finalGrade,average;
    private static ArrayList<Students> studentList;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public StudentTable() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param lastName
     * @param studentId
     * @param quiz1
     * @param quiz2
     * @param project
     * @param midterm
     * @param finalGrade
     * @param average
     * @param letterGrade
     */
    public StudentTable(String name, String lastName, long studentId, double quiz1, double quiz2, double project, double midterm, double finalGrade, double average, String letterGrade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.letterGrade = letterGrade;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.quiz1 = quiz1;
        this.quiz2 = quiz2;
        this.project = project;
        this.midterm = midterm;
        this.finalGrade = finalGrade;
        this.average = average;
    }

    // GET & SET METHODS
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getLetterGrade() {
        return letterGrade;
    }
    public void setLetterGrade(String letterGrade) {
        this.letterGrade = letterGrade;
    }
    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public double getQuiz1() {
        return quiz1;
    }
    public void setQuiz1(double quiz1) {
        this.quiz1 = quiz1;
    }
    public double getQuiz2() {
        return quiz2;
    }
    public void setQuiz2(double quiz2) {
        this.quiz2 = quiz2;
    }
    public double getProject() {
        return project;
    }
    public void setProject(double project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
    public double getMidterm() {
        return midterm;
    }
    public void setMidterm(double midterm) {
        this.midterm = midterm;
    }
    public double getFinalGrade() {
        return finalGrade;
    }
    public void setFinalGrade(double finalGrade) {
        this.finalGrade = finalGrade;
    }
    public double getAverage() {
        return average;
    }
    public void setAverage(double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }
    public ArrayList<Students> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }
    public void setStudentList(ArrayList<Students> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    // Opening "Students.txt" file from a url.
    public void openFile() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://rawsly.com/Students.txt");
            scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Reading "Students.txt" file and adding students to the "studentList" ArrayList.
    public void readFile() {
        studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            name = scanner.next();
            lastName = scanner.next();
            studentId = scanner.nextLong();
            quiz1 = scanner.nextDouble();
            quiz2 = scanner.nextDouble();
            project = scanner.nextDouble();
            midterm = scanner.nextDouble();
            finalGrade = scanner.nextDouble();
            average = scanner.nextDouble();
            letterGrade = scanner.next();
            studentList.add(new Students(name, lastName, studentId, quiz1, quiz2, project, midterm, finalGrade, average, letterGrade));
        }
    }

    // Closing "Students.txt" file.
    public void closeFile() {
        scanner.close();
    }

    public void createTable() {
        openFile();
        readFile();
        closeFile();
        String [] columnNames = {"NAME", "SURNAME", "ID", "QUIZ1", "QUIZ2", "PROJECT", "MIDTERM", "FINAL", "AVERAGE", "LETTER GRADE"};
        Object [][] data = new Object[studentList.size()][10];
        for(int i=0; i<studentList.size(); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    data[i][0] = studentList.get(i).getName();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    data[i][1] = studentList.get(i).getLastName();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    data[i][2] = studentList.get(i).getStudentId();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    data[i][3] = studentList.get(i).getQuiz1();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    data[i][4] = studentList.get(i).getQuiz2();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    data[i][5] = studentList.get(i).getProject();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    data[i][6] = studentList.get(i).getMidterm();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    data[i][7] = studentList.get(i).getFinalGrade();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    data[i][8] = studentList.get(i).getAverage();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    data[i][9] = studentList.get(i).getLetterGrade();
                    break;
                } // end of the switch
            } // end of the first for loop
        } // end of the second for loop

        table = new JTable(data,columnNames) {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { // To make row and columns not editable
                return false;
            }
        };
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); // to activate sorting property of each column
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentTable s = new StudentTable();
        s.createTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question. Second, you did nothing with the created `JTable`  so at least add a getter in `StudentTable` use it to get the `JTable` in `Screen` and add that `JTable` into the appropriate panel. Third, rethink your code twice, there is numerous bad things in it.

Comment: Okay, I am gonna work on it again. Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Comment: I see you are adding the table by `PList.add(studentTable);` . What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: Yes, but when I run the program, I don't see anything in "PList" tab. I guess I have to work on GUI more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you're creating a Panel with a Table in the screen class.

```
studentTable = new StudentTable();
```

This is what the constructor for StudentTable looks like.

```
public StudentTable() {}
```

You see the problem here? You're calling an empty constructor.

You can try to fix it by actually creating the table, either in the table constructor or by explicitly calling `createTable()` on the object.

So either in `Screen` do.

```
// Tabs
tabbedPane.add("List", PList);
tabbedPane.add("Chart", PChart);
add(tabbedPane);
studentTable.createTable(); // Create the table
PList.add(studentTable);
validate(); // Revalidate the frame
```

Or in the create the table in the `StudentTable` class.

```
public StudentTable() {
    createTable();
}
```

See, that simple. Does it work now? Not really. StudentTable is a `Panel`, and you never actually add anything to it. So you're just adding an empty Panel to your TabbedPane.

You need to actually add the table to the Panel at some point. So go back to the `StudentTable` Class and add `add(table)` at the end of the `createTable()` method. Or if you're calling createTable() in the constructor, you can also add this line in the constructor, below createTable().

```
public StudentTable() {
    createTable();
    add(table);
}
```

Can you see a table now? Yes you can. Can you see all the values in the table? No you cannot. That's because the table isn't scrollable. You need to add it to a `ScrollPane`.

The easiest way to go about it is to create a `ScrollPane` in the `StudentTable` Class. Add the `Table` to the `ScrollPane` and then add the `ScrollPane` to the `Panel`.

Go back to where ever you wrote `add(table)` in the `StudentTable` Class and **replace** with.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
add(scrollPane);
```

This should fix your problem for now.

As an additional, I want to point out that you use way too many class fields. For example in the `StudentTable` Class, `name`, `lastName`, `letterGrade`, `studentId`, `quiz1`, `quiz2`, `project`, `midterm`, `finalGrade`, `average` and `scanner` have no use being a field. All but one are not attributes of the table, they don't represent an instance of a table. They represent a `Student` I would suggest you to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527183/6015444) to a related question.

> You should never use a field to simplify passing data from one method to another method. That's simply not its purpose. Doing so also makes your methods intrinsically thread unsafe or require synchronization.

You also do not need a `main()` method in every single class. It just serves as an entry point to the code when it starts, that's it.

Regarding the getters and setter, only add the ones you need. Your `screen` Class accesses none of the fields in the `StudentTable` class (understandably since most of them are not justified and would be completely useless to other classes), yet you have a getter and setter for every single one of them.
If you do have a lot of getter and setter, put them at the end, this stops having to scroll 20 minutes to access any of the actual implementation in the class.

Here is how I would have probably written the `StudentTable` Class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class StudentTablePanel extends JPanel {

    private static JTable table;

    public StudentTablePanel() {
        table = createTable(getStudentList()); // This line—in my opinion—makes it more immediately understandable what is happening, you're creating a table from a list of students.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    // Reading "Students.txt" file and adding students to the "studentList" ArrayList.
    public ArrayList<Students> getStudentList() {
        ArrayList<Students> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new URL("http://rawsly.com/Students.txt").openStream())) { // Try with resources loop automatically closes the scanner when done
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String name = scanner.next();
                String lastName = scanner.next();
                long studentId = scanner.nextLong();
                double quiz1 = scanner.nextDouble();
                double quiz2 = scanner.nextDouble();
                double project = scanner.nextDouble();
                double midterm = scanner.nextDouble();
                double finalGrade = scanner.nextDouble();
                double average = scanner.nextDouble();
                String letterGrade = scanner.next();
                list.add(new Students(name, lastName, studentId, quiz1, quiz2, project, midterm, finalGrade, average, letterGrade));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Handle your exception
        }
        return list;
    }

    public JTable createTable(ArrayList<Students> studentList) {
        String[] columnNames = {"NAME", "SURNAME", "ID", "QUIZ1", "QUIZ2", "PROJECT", "MIDTERM", "FINAL", "AVERAGE", "LETTER GRADE"};
        int row = studentList.size();
        int column = columnNames.length;
        Object[][] data = new Object[row][column];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                switch (j) {
                    case 0:
                        data[i][0] = studentList.get(i).getName();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        data[i][1] = studentList.get(i).getLastName();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        data[i][2] = studentList.get(i).getStudentId();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        data[i][3] = studentList.get(i).getQuiz1();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        data[i][4] = studentList.get(i).getQuiz2();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        data[i][5] = studentList.get(i).getProject();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        data[i][6] = studentList.get(i).getMidterm();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        data[i][7] = studentList.get(i).getFinalGrade();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        data[i][8] = studentList.get(i).getAverage();
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        data[i][9] = studentList.get(i).getLetterGrade();
                } // end of the switch
            } // end of the first for loop
        } // end of the second for loop

        JTable newTable= new JTable(data, columnNames) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { // To make row and columns not editable
                return false;
            }
        };
        newTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        newTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); // to activate sorting property of each column

        return newTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much for your comment! I am gonna study your explanations very carefully.